# Can section headings be questions for APA format?

Tags: style, formatting, essay, apa

I would want my first heading to be "What is Lyme disease '.' '?'" , Im not sure if it would be considered a question or a sentence . I want this paragraph to inform the reader what the definition is.

Answer (score 1):

In academic articles, headings more often than not tend to be topic phrases, rather than sentences, but this depends to a large extent on authorial style.

It would be perfectly acceptable to change 'What is Lyme disease?' to 'Lyme Disease: A Definition'

Do not, however, put a period/full stop after a Level 1 heading ('What Is Lyme Disease.'), or leave a question mark off the question-form heading ('What Is Lyme Disease').

Note also the convention of using Title Case for APA headings.

In the Introduction section of the APA Style Guide, 7th Edition, pp xvii and xviii, two interrogative sentence headings appear: 'Why Use APA Style?' and 'What's New in the Seventh Edition?' However, the formatting of an academic paper is not the same as the formatting of a book - an academic paper would not need 'Introduction' as a header, for example - in fact, this is advised against, but it does have a place in a book. The same argument might well be applied to the use of questions as headings more acceptable in a book than in an academic paper.

More info on formatting headings in APA style can be found on the APA Blog [here](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/headings).